# LAN based app - How to connect without static IP?

Tags: c#, networking, ip, lan

I am developing a LAN-based database application. It involves a central "server" app to house the database, along with many "client" applications that access it.

The "server" will be a simple C#-based HTTP server that responds to GET and POST requests. However, since it is designed to be able to run from any laptop on the network, I am wondering how to establish the connection between clients and the server without knowing the IP address.

I suppose I could ping every IP address from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.255, and then test those that responded to see if any are my server. But I would only do that if there is no better way. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address

Comment: You could have the service announce itself, more details about your network would be helpful to answer this question. What assigns the IP addresses? Is this a windows domain? Do you have a local DNS server?

Comment: The network is simply a router connected to a few PCs and laptops.. no DNS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of these types of discovery services run by putting out some kind of beacon on either the subnet broadcast address (for 192.168.0.0/24 it would be 192.168.0.255) or by putting out a beacon on a multicast address.

Multicast is particularly interesting because in a properly configured network, it allows hosts to find the service even across subnets. Routers and switches won't generally forward broadcast packets across subnet boundaries, but multicast packets will.

The beacon would have information in it such as the port the service is running on, what type of service it is, whatever is needed to start using the service.

Comment: Thanks - this led me right to the answer. I was trying a UDP broadcast but as you suggested, it didn't work through my router. Multicasting is exactly what I needed to do: http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/

Comment: The jarloo link in another comment is dead.  Here is the wayback link:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200701165633/http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

To head you in the right direction, what you should do is have the database server running on a specified port.  Then send out a [broadcast](http://blog.eviac.com/2010/12/network-broadcasting-with-c.html) to that port from the client (the system needing to connect to the database).  When the database server receives this, it will be able to respond to the sender, allowing a handshake to occur.

Of course, you will need to validate the database server's authenticity (to make it secure, unless you aren't worried about that).  This can be as simple as having the client display 4 numbers which then need to be typed into the database, so that the database can send the 4 numbers back to the client proving it is the right computer (how the iTunes remote works), or you can use certificates (but that is too complex a topic for me to cover correctly).

After that the two computers will know each others IPs, and you're set!